# how to call a function in code behind from an external .js file

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i am developing a website in dotnet.

```
//function to close SearchSchool.aspx
function CloseSchoolSearch()    
{
    //storing values
    window.close();
    //call function in code behind
}
```

This is a javascript function in an external .js file ,using this function i am storing some values in some hidden controls in an aspx page and closing pop window ,after that i want to execute a function in code behind.and remind one thing,i can't include this function .aspx page contaning that method i want to call.Can anyone guide me how to do this

Comment: are you asking how to save the values in the previous page or how to call the function in the previous page?

Comment: you want to call a function of .aspx page from javascript?

Comment: yes ,from external .js file

Comment: Is it a javascript function?

Comment: want to call a function in codebehind(c#) from a external javascript file

Comment: your aspx page is a server page which gets converted to html when it reaches the client. Hence, the .aspx function is not at all available there. If you want to call such a function please use ajax calls.

Comment: how can i do that?can u show me an example?

Answer (score 1):

As i understand the question, you are talking about 2 very different things.
the .ASPX page is rendered on the server and the javascript code is rendered at the client side.

for you to call a function from the aspx page from JS means that you need to make a call to the server to render your page is some other manner with a parameter you mentioned in your call.

only then will the server re-render the page (can be ajax as well) and invoke these methods.

other then that, the server side code is not being sent to the client side.

**On the client side:**

you can use any framework or implement your own. i'll use jquery for simplicity

> ```
> /* attach a submit handler to the form */
>  $("#form_name").submit(function(event) {
> /* stop form from submitting normally */
> event.preventDefault();
> ```

```
/* get some values from elements on the page: */
    url ="<server url>";

var $inputs = $('#form_name :input');

var dataString="";
$inputs.each(function() {
    if (this.type != "submit" && this.type != "button")
    dataString += (this.name +"="+ $(this).val() +"&").trim();

});

/*Remove the & at the end of the string*/
dataString = dataString.slice(0, -1);

/* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
$.post( url, dataString,
  function( data ) {
  }
);
```

the serialize function will work as well just add its output instead of the dataString.

Comment: thanks for the valuable imformation.can u show me an example for this

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to call a javascript function defined inside the HTML page using `<script></script>` from an externally loaded `.js` file.

Just make sure the internal javascript function is available when your external JS is loaded.

If you want to call a function `localFoo()` defined inside the HTML code, then do this:

```
// Check for the function availability
if(typeof localFoo != undefined) {
    localFoo(arg);
}
```